# Logging a message in Rollbar makes php error disappear

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, rollbar

I use Rollbar error monitoring and I get an error:

> ErrorException: Undefined offset: 1

I can't really pin down the location of the error because it happens in the compiled code:

> File /var/www/laravel/storage/framework/views/8d64d770d97f73443e576b8d42e0405f220c2c4e.php line 386

The blade.php page does not render.

However when I just put a statement:

```
 Log::info("im here!");
```

in an attempt to find the location, the page renders completely fine. The error in the rollbar log remains though.

What could be a smarter way to deal with this / find the reason for the error message ? :-)

Comment: go to the compile code and find nearest functions and methods in the error line and Use sublime to do full site search

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please add your Blade template and learn how to include a Minimal Reproducable Example here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ErrorException: Undefined offset: 1

The error means that you're trying to access an array value by key 1 in your Blade template where no such key exists

Find the code that looks like this `$arrayName[1]`

Make sure that your array isn't null and that it has at least two values in it (arrays are zero 0 indexed which means that 1 is the second value)

And if the value on key 1 is optional, you can wrap the call with an `if statement`

```
@if (array_key_exists(1, $arrayName)
    {{ $arrayName[1] }}
@endif
```